# Merging type declarations with conditional types

Tags: typescript

When a union of types are passed through a conditional type in TypeScript the returned value is not consistent when the conditional is removed.

When given a union of types typescript correctly merges the possible parameters into each parameter.

```js
type Fn<T> = (arg: T) => void
Fn<string | number> // (arg: string | number) => void
```

However, when a conditional parameter is in the mix, the argument is  resolved

```js
type ConditionalFn<T> = T extends never ? Fn<T> : Fn<T>
ConditionalFn<string | number> // Fn<string> | Fn<number>
// That is equivalent to which is ((arg: string) => void | (arg: number) => void)
```

Usually this wouldn't be an issue. But when a function's type is set to the conditional kind, the argument's are all set to `any` and a manual cast would be required.

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Fn%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0Atype%20ConditionalFn%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20number%20%3F%20Fn%3CT%3E%20%3A%20Fn%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20simple%20%3D%20Fn%3Cstring%20%7C%20number%3E%0D%0Atype%20complex%20%3D%20ConditionalFn%3Cstring%20%7C%20number%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test1%3A%20simple%20%3D%20arg%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20arg%20%3D%3D%20'string')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('arg%20is%20string')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(typeof%20arg%20%3D%3D%20'number')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('arg%20is%20number')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20Error('unreachable')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test2%3A%20complex%20%3D%20arg%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20arg%20%3D%3D%20'string')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('arg%20is%20string')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(typeof%20arg%20%3D%3D%20'number')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('arg%20is%20number')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20Error('unreachable')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

I expect `ConditionalFn<string | number>` to resolve to `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` and then further resolved to `Fn<string | number>`.

---

[Follow up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Fn%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0Atype%20ConditionalFn%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20number%20%3F%20Fn%3CT%3E%20%3A%20Fn%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20objA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'name'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3F%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20objB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'name'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20more%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20test1%3A%20Fn%3CobjA%20%7C%20objB%3E%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20test2%3A%20Fn%3CobjA%3E%20%7C%20Fn%3CobjB%3E%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20test3%3A%20ConditionalFn%3CobjA%20%7C%20objB%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atest1(%7B%20name%3A%20'name'%2C%20data%3A%2012%20%7D)%0D%0Atest2(%7B%20name%3A%20'name'%2C%20data%3A%2012%20%7D)%0D%0Atest3(%7B%20name%3A%20'name'%2C%20data%3A%2012%20%7D)%0D%0A)

Why does the `f` variable in the [Improved behavior for calling union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)
 example require an intersection for the argument types?
I think that is root cause for my confusion. Since it forces the argument types to be `any` if there isn't any intersection.

Comment: "Why does the `f` variable require an intersection for the argument types?" The example explains it.  It's a consequence of contravariance of argument types.  You can see how "or" (union) switches to "and" (intersection) if you think what a union of functions actually is.  Imagine a pair of identical twins, Jen and Jan.  I know that Jen likes to eat vegetables of all kinds, and I know that Jan likes to eat any food that's organic.  One of them is coming to dinner, but I don't know which.  It will be either Jen *or* Jan.  What can I safely feed my mystery guest?

Comment: I can't feed her a conventional (not organic) eggplant, because Jan might not like something not organinc.  I can't feed her an organic steak, because if it's Jen, she might not like meat.  The only safe bet is something like an organic eggplant... something which is both organic *and* a vegetable.  A union of functions requires an intersection of parameters.

Comment: Perfect, that description makes sense. Before I thought a union of the arguments shouldve worked. But I understand the contravariance now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional type you're using is [distributive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) and expands `ConditionalFn<string | number>` to `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` as you expect.  But `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` *is not assignable to* `Fn<string | number>`.  Those are quite different types.

`Fn<string | number>` is a very specific type of function; one which can accept both `string` and `number` arguments.  It is a single function that says "I don't care if the argument is a `string` or a `number`; I will accept either of them".

Now a function of type `Fn<string>` is only required to accept a `string`, and function of type `Fn<number>` is only required to accept a `number`.  And a function of type `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` is *one of those*, we just don't know which one.  It's quite an unspecific/vague function type.  And therefore it's hard to actually call a function of such a type (prior to TS3.3 you couldn't call it at all without a type assertion), since the only way I could confidently pass it a parameter would be to give it something which is both a `string` and a `number`; that is, a `string & number`.  TypeScript 3.3 added [support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for calling such unions-of-functions with intersections, which is great... except that no values of type `string & number` exist; it is equivalent to `never`.  So it is not possible to safely call a function of type `ConditionalFn<string | number>`, and that is likely the cause of your issue.

Just to reiterate the difference between these types: The function `(a: number) => console.log(2-a)` is a valid `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` (since it is a `Fn<number>`) but it is *not* a valid `Fn<string | number>` (since it does not accept strings).

This does tend to confuse people because function types narrow/widen in the *opposite* direction from their argument types.  This is called [contravariance](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) and TypeScript has supported it since version 2.6.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood or misexplained it.
When the argument types overlap, the argument is a Union for `Fn<string | number>` but an intersection for `Fn<string> | Fn<number>` which is expected.

But without any overlap it seems that the `ConditionalFn` doesn't have any type for the argument of the function.

Edited my answer with a new playground link.

Comment: Yes, if `A & B` is `never`, then `((x: A)=>void) | ((x: B)=>void)` cannot safely accept any argument.  I think my answer covers this, so I'm not sure where you are still confused.